# Einstein dataflow sync node error

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

I am trying to create a data set for Campaign object in our sandbox but get an error on Sync
Campaign (Replication) when the dataflow runs:

Something went wrong while executing the Sync_Campaign node: Fields [CloneSourceId, ShowCampMembChart] are not available. Verify that the fields exists and that the Analytics Cloud Integration User profile has Read level access on the fields. (02KN0000000WOZFMA4_03CN0000001tt4bMAA)

I tried looking for these fields on the Campaign object but its not there. What object has those fields for me to give access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. For anyone else who may encounter a similar issue.

Even though the fields are unchecked in my sfdcDigest, they need to be unchecked in Data Manager -> Connect -> SFDC_LOCAL -> Campaign object

When I ran my dataflow again it no longer had any issues.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

I too had a similar error but while creating a different dataset while working on Trailhead modules.

The error says "Something went wrong while executing the sfdcDigest_Account node: Error accessing synced dataset. [error category: USER]: Invalid extract field name [BillingCity] (02K5g000001ICJNEA4_03C5g000003b2MYEAY)".

With the information given in this thread, I had fixed it as follows.

[image]

[image]

I got an error while synching in the data from Accounts objects. When I looked in connect tab in Data Manager, Accounts & User are orange out while other objects are in green. This is because data is not yet synced from these 2 objects.
Below screenshot shows accounts in green as I had synced it before writing this thread.
[image]

So, now click on down arrow at the end of account/user and select run syn now and run the dataflow again. This will fix the error.

Now, I had to sync user object as well and then run dataflow to be successful.